# Spring: Two beans implementing one interface with one as @Primary - autowiring creates both beans

Tags: java, spring

One Interface: `BeanMapperUtil`

Two implementing beans:

1. `OrikaBeanMapper` - Singleton bean and marked `@Primary`
2. `DirectBeanMapper` - prototype bean

In Manager class:

```
@Autowired
BeanMapperUtil mapper;
```

**Observation:** Spring creates both `OrikaBeanMapper` and `DirectBeanMapper` and then autowires `OrikaBeanMapper`.

**Expected:** Since `OrikaBeanMapper` is already marked as `@Primary`, Spring should create only this bean and autowire it. Spring need not create an instance of `DirectBeanMapper`. There is no impact on performance/functionality, but this looks like wasteful creation of instance only to be discarded.

Comment: When your application starts Spring creates instance of all the beans which are register in that and stores that bean in the BeanFactory. Hence all beans are created at once and only BeanMapperUtil is injected.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate i think this is true only for singletone beans and not prototype beans. Prototype beans are expected to be created on demand.

Answer (score 0):

When your application starts, Spring container creates instance of all the beans(expect prototype bean) which are register in that and stores that bean in the BeanFactory.

Hence all beans are created at once and only BeanMapperUtil is injected as it is used for autowiring.

Answer (score 0):

`@Primary` works as a filter after all matching beans have been created. It's not designed to prevent the lookup and creation of other, non-primary, matching beans.

When Spring tries to autowire `BeanMapperUtil`, it will find two matches, `OrikaBeanMapper` and `DirectBeanMapper`, and both will be created. At this point the `@Primary` comes into play. Spring will choose the bean with the `@Primary` annotation for injection.